# Custom Post Types with a common category for a blog listing

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

My client wants to have the ability to call up a common category used in multiple custom post types. So if there is a common category of "budget", then a blog listing would come up with all the custom post types that have a category of "budget".

I read up on a few examples here of using args for different post types, and pieced them together on a custom template called "page-category-budgeting.php". This is in a child theme based on Twenty-twelve.

After testing and working through some debugging, I'm still without success. The latest error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/acs10047/public_html/wp-content/themes/moneysmartfamily/page-category-budgeting.php on line 53"

But that is a blank line at the end of the code. I have nothing to go with to figure this out. Here is the template code. I must be missing something simple or overlooking how this should be set up. Could someone advise me as to what I'm missing? Thanks.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Category - Budgeting
 *
 *
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); 

    $args = array('post_type' => array('post','media-appearance','members-archive','money-saving-tips','review'),
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
);

    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php while ( $this_query->have_posts()) : $this_query->the_post(); {?>

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ($cat == 'budget') ): ?>
    <div class="tip-excerpt">                                     
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>        

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php  // done the foreach statement ?>


    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another topic created here gave me the answer... very simple args structure now that I know.

```
 get_header(); 

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'any', //or use cpt slug as string, or array of strings if multiple
      'category_name' => 'budget', //use 'budget,premium' if you want posts with budget OR premium, use 'budget+premium' if you want budget AND premium. 
    );


    // This query should now only have the post_type in the args above that are in the category budget.
    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?> 


<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php 
    if ( $this_query->have_posts() ) :



        while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post(); 
            $post_id = get_the_ID(); // In case you need to use the post ID
            ?>

            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
        <header class="entry-header">

            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <span class="post-meta">Author  <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  | <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->


              <div class="entry-summary">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->


            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<?php endwhile; ?>` before the end of content div.

```
get_header(); 

    $args = array('post_type' => array('post','media-appearance','members-archive','money-saving-tips','review'),
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
);

    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php while ( $this_query->have_posts()) : $this_query->the_post(); {?>

        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() && ($cat == 'budget') ): ?>
    <div class="tip-excerpt">                                     
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>        

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php  // done the foreach statement ?>

     <?php endwhile; ?> //ADDED CODE
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for noticing that. In my debugging I had an "expected endwhile" and removed it and it kicked the next issue. In the codex it had an example without an endwhile so I guessed it was okay to not use that. Apparently not. I'll try that out.

Comment: Nope, that's not working. By the way, I noted that you missed a ? before the end > of your code addition. 

I tried this and got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /home/acs10047/public_html/wp-content/themes/moneysmartfamily/page-category-budgeting.php on line 47". What would cause that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I made some modifications to your code. you can message me if you need help with the layout of the elements.

```
    get_header(); 

    $args = array(
        'category_name'  => array(
            'budget'
        ), // category_name (string) – use category slug.
    );

    // This query should now only have the post_type in the args above that are in the category budget.
    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?> 


<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php 
    if ( $this_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post(); 
            $post_id = get_the_ID(); // In case you need to use the post ID
            ?>

            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
        <header class="entry-header">

            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <span class="post-meta">Author  <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  | <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->


              <div class="entry-summary">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a>

            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->


            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        endwhile;

    endif;
    ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rudy. I see a couple significant things you did here by putting a category_name array in the args (besides tidying up the post type presentation - nice). I haven't done much with queries in my development and this project request is getting me some long overdue exposure to the concept. I'll give it a try.

Comment: It seems to have worked! I'll have to verify with my client if it is indeed calling up from the different CPTs as he'll be able to tell better. I'll follow up with more info.

Comment: If it worked can you please mark as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is showing the current blog roll. If you compare the test page (https://moneysmartfamily.com/?page_id=22149) with the normal blog page (https://moneysmartfamily.com/blog/), you'll see the items are the same. If you look at one of their existing category pages (here is "budget": https://moneysmartfamily.com/?cat=214) that would seem to be the items we should be seeing in the new test page.

Comment: Your args seemed sound. Anyway, I posted an updated template as an answer. I added more template to style the page more like the client's blog. Sorry, but the paste-in got wonky and I had to combine lines so that everything showed up.

Comment: @DavidBorrink Here is updated code that is only doing a query for those posts that are in the budget category. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, Rudy. I tried it and it's still listing only the full blog roll from posts. I'm not sure what's happening here. Your query is only for "budget", yet it shows more categories than just the budget ones. And I verified the slug name just to be sure. https://moneysmartfamily.com/budgeting-category-test/

I know that when I was trying to figure out the query setup that there was a reset query line in the end. We don't have one of those in there. Is that affecting it? I know I called the query "this_query" to give it a different name than a normal query. I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: So baffling. I'm trying things like: 
`$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'money-saving-tips',
        'category_name'  => 'budget', );`
 in the args and I'm still getting the regular post lineup. I'm not seeing why the regular post lineup is showing up when it's clear we've defined post_types and category in the args.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Place a test text somewhere in your code and check the page to see if the text parses. I am thinking that your page is not pointed to where you are putting your code. You can pm me if you want me to directly help you.

Comment: Okay, the site cache wasn't clearing. My fault. I'm getting budget-only categories with the money-saving-tips CPT. I used the query args from my last entry just above. I went in and added 'posts' to the args, and  got the regular blog roll with all categories and just the 'budget' posts from 'money-saving-tips', even though 'budget' was the only category name specified. The question is: why is adding 'post' resulting in all posts in all cats, when the query is just for 'budget'? July 25 is where the first 'money-saving-tips' post is.

Comment: `$args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'money-saving-tips',
            'post'
        ),
    'category_name'  => array(
        'budget'
    ),
);`

Comment: This is happening because the category name is not an excluding method. It is an addition of positive calls. Meaning the query is looking for all posts that match the args you are passing in. None of those args are excluding posts. There for by adding posts to the post type args is just calling for all the other posts as well as the budget category. If this helped you can you please mark as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I see. I did some research here and found some topics that may give me a clue. Would adding something like this to the args help? Would this work to be more specific and exclude categories? `'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'fields' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('slug-1', 'slug-2')
            )
        ),`

Comment: Or does this post speak to the issue?...https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/search-pre-get-posts-filter-which-can-handle-multiple-post-types-and-categories   I appreciate your opinion if this would be more in the direction of what I'm wanting to do. My request would appear to be a unique situation, given how few examples came up with "custom post types" and "exclude category".

Comment: I am not understanding what you are wanting now, I thought you were asking how to get all posts by the category budget. you said it worked after clearing cache and I am now confused about what you are wanting to exclude. So what are you trying to exclude?

Comment: What's happening now is that with the post types of "post" and "money saving tips" with a category array of "budget", I'm getting ALL "posts" regardless of category and the "money saving tips" posts. It's not giving me only the "budget" posts. You said that category name is not an excluding method. So I looked to see if there were some other posts here on SE that would address the idea of excluding categories, and I showed examples of a code that used a terms array and wondered if these were concepts that should be used.

Comment: I tried this: `$args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'money-saving-tips',
            'post'
        ),
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'fields' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('budget')
            )` but it didn't give me just 'budget' categories for both of those post types.

Comment: So taking off the the post_type from the query should just get you all posts that are in the budget category. you said that worked and then you seem to be trying to do something else, that is the part that I am confused about. what is your goal? If it is just to get the budget category then take off the post_type and clear your cache.

Comment: The goal, again, is to have all 'budget' category posts from all post types on the output for this page. What I'm getting is all the 'post' posts of all categories, plus the 'money saving tips' posts but with only the 'budget' category. I have cleared the cache. With the following query args in my next comment, I should not be getting all the categories of 'post's. I don't understand why I'm getting only 'budget' categories in 'money saving tips' but not with normal 'post's. And the additional code I put in there is to try and see if I can subtract categories.

Comment: Current page output: https://moneysmartfamily.com/?page_id=22149 . 

The code I referred to is this....  
`$args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'money-saving-tips',
            'post'
        ),
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'fields' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('budget')
            )
        ),
);`

Comment: You mentioned that 'category_name' is not an excluding method, so I'm trying something from another topic here (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/search-pre-get-posts-filter-which-can-handle-multiple-post-types-and-categories) that sounded like it might be more specific.

Comment: You said "The goal, again, is to have all 'budget' category posts from all post types on the output for this page." The args I gave you above without the post_type should get you all posts of all post types. You do not need to add anymore args.

Comment: Thanks again for your time in working through this. I posted a new topic to get some fresh eyes and the answer is on this page with the check mark. I pasted the code that works. You'll see the args structure someone else gave. Now that we finally know, this can help others.